# Need help with getting friends of Twitter user; using PHP and Epiphany RESTful PHP Framework

Tags: php, twitter

I am trying to get friends of the username I am passing in. Will not work, have tried everything I can think of. Please look over and give me some suggestions:

Although it gives no errors, a blank page is displayed. No usernames are echoed.

```
include 'lib/EpiCurl.php';
include 'lib/EpiOAuth.php';
include 'lib/EpiTwitter.php';
include 'lib/secret.php';

$twitterObj = new EpiTwitter($consumer_key, $consumer_secret);
$oauth_token = 'xxxx'; //Yes I filled these out in the actual code
$oauth_token_secret = 'xxxx'; //Yes I filled these out in the actual code

$twitterObj->setToken($oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
$twitterInfo= $twitterObj->get_accountVerify_credentials();
$twitterInfo->response;
$twitterUsername = $twitterInfo->screen_name;

getFriends('csti');

function getFriends ($username){

global $twitterObj, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret, $twitterUsername;

$twitterFriends = $twitterObj->get('/statuses/friends.json');
$twitterFriends->response; //not sure if this is necessary but doesnt work either way.

    try{  
      foreach($twitterFriends as $friend) {  
        echo $friend->screen_name;  
      }
    }catch(EpiTwitterException $e){  
      echo $e->getMessage();  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got a bit of weirdness in your code.

Your passing the parameter `$username` and the string `'csti'` but you don't seem to be using it anywhere in the function.

Comment: Ilya, that's how 'global' works in PHP as far as i know: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php. That variable is there from a previous version. This should actually get friends of that variable but yes right now its doing nothing.

Comment: interesting, learned something new. I think this will help me solve some problems with an undefined object I've been having across my MVC pattern. I'll edit my post.

Comment: what happens if you `var_dump($twitterObj);` are you getting anything?